# Excel Automation

Tags: c#, excel

Does everyone know how to create custom button in the excel that display simple window form in csharp language?
For example:
A button called "Show" in the excel toolbar that show messagebox pop up.

Comment: edited tags. This doesn't apply to automation. It is just the creation of a button.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this for starters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289518(VS.71).aspx